# UITableView paddings between text and detail text labels (ios, xamarin)

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

I have a UITableView with 2 text labels inside.
I want to move them a little.

I found a property for whole cell height, but thats not one im looking for.

Which property can help me?

here is the code:

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace iOSInputOutput
{
    public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
    {

        List<string> gameNamesList;
        List<string> gameIdsList;

        string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";

        public TableSource(List<string> games, List<string> ids)
        {
            gameNamesList = games;
            gameIdsList = ids;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return gameIdsList.Count;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier);
            //recucle cells that away from vision on screen

            if (cell == null)
                cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellIdentifier);
            cell.TextLabel.Text = gameNamesList[indexPath.Row];


            cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = gameIdsList[indexPath.Row];

            //tableView.RowHeight = (nfloat) 124.0;

            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom UITableViewCell and place labels as you wish inside it, don't try manipulating apples's default UITableViewCell...

Just subclass UITableViewCell

```
 class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

let titleLabel: UILabel = {
     let myVar = UILabel()
    myVar.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    return myVar
 }()

let detailLabel: UILabel = {
    let myVar = UILabel()
    myVar.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    return myVar
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    self.contentView.addSubview(detalLabel)
    self.setUp()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

 func setUp() {

   // here you do what you want with your labels (position them as you like)

 }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, so hard to get any answers for xamarin here. 
seems like very rare platform or idk why its happens

Comment: btw how to move them in setUp()?

Comment: I am using SnapKit to set up constraints.  titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(self.snp.bottom).offset(3)
            make.width.height.equalTo(self.snp.height).multipliedBy(0.4)
            make.centerX.equalTo(self.snp.centerX)
        }